# Backup drive regularly spins up

Tags: hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive, macos-mojave

I have an iMac and have an external USB3 WD disk connected to it. I use this drive for CCC backups. I always have the backup partitions/drives unmounted. In disk utility they are greyed out and I have to right-click "mount" them to access them. CCC will mount the drives when it does its scheduled backups.

When I am not using my iMac I notice that the external drive spins up about every 5 minutes for about 30-60 seconds and then spins down again. The screen remains dark, and the drives do not seem to get mounted, the only thing I notice is that I can see a lot of `diskarbitrationd` entries in `Console`. The message is `private` so I can't really see any further details. 
Does anyone have a clue what could be causing these unnecessary constant drive spin-ups? 
I have excluded that backup partitions from Spotlight's index, so that can't be the cause

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two probable reasons for this. 1. I'm guessing it's a WD "My Book". But in any case, the drive is "spun down" for a couple reasons; 1 to save energy, and 2 for longevity (of the drive). In any case. The reason you're seeing the drive activity, is because MacOS occasionally "polls" the drive, to insure it's there. But given the drive has spun down, it must be reinitialized (woke up).

I might also add that the controller on these drives may begin to fail, which may also cause this type of activity. But until, or unless you begin to see "hard fails", or other problems. You need not be concerned. You might also like to know. That if the drive ever *does* show signs of failure. It's more than likely the controller, and not the drive. So it's a simple matter of removing the controller from the drive, and given that it's likely a SATA drive. You can either get another (empty) external USB box, or simply hook it up to any computer with a (spare) SATA interface, and use it, or simply retrieve the data from it.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is indeed a MyBook. It is not that I am worried about the drive failing. It is simply an annoyance to have it spin up for 30 seconds and then turn off again. Especially when the room is otherwise completely quiet. I was already thinking about doing an overkill and putting the drive on a timed power outlet so that it only does this, when I am not there.